# wix WixStdbaLicenseUrl doesn't hide license when custom theme used

Tags: wix, burn

I use this to hide the license dialogue

```
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseUrl" Value=""/
```

which works, until I introduce a custom theme using

```
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaThemeXml" Value="Resource\RtfTheme.xml" />
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaThemeWxl" Value="Resource\RtfTheme.wxl" />
```

My theme is just a copy of  the built in RtfTheme, trivially tweaked. I changed the window size, and removed the repair button.

When I do this, the license dialogue is presented (although with empty text).  I want the dialogue to remain hidden.

Why?  How to fix?

Here is one of several variations I've tried:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense" >
    <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            LicenseFile="..\..\Tools\Building\buildIncludes\LicenseAgreement-Memo.rtf"
      LogoFile="..\..\Tools\Building\buildIncludes\my.logo.png"
            SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
   />

</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
<!-- supress license display in boot strapper -->
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseUrl" Value=""/>
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseFile" Value=""/>
<!-- we are using a customized theme -->
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaThemeXml" Value="Resource\RtfTheme.xml" />
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaThemeWxl" Value="Resource\RtfTheme.wxl" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I should have known... Since I'm using a custom theme, I can address the problem by editing RthTheme.xml to remove the controls for the rtf license text and the accept button.

Still, it may be a bug that setting WixStdbaLicenseUrl to empty string doesn't work when using a custom theme.

Here's hoping that I get my own bonus points!

Answer (score 6):

The RTF based license theme theme does not provide a way to hide the RTF dialog by default. You can edit the theme to remove the RTF license and accept checkbox yourself.

The Hyperlink based license theme **does** provide a way to hide the license hyperlink and the accept checkbox by setting the the `bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` element's `LicenseUrl` attribute to `""`.

So, to answer your question, I would recommend doing something like:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl=""
       LogoFile="="..\..\Tools\Building\buildIncludes\"
       ThemeFile="Resources\CustomHyperlinkBasedTheme.xml" />

  <Payload SourceFile="Resources\OtherStuffIfYouNeed.It" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaThemeWxl" Value="Resources\CustomHyperlinkBasedTheme.wxl" />
```

The important part is to base your custom theme on the hyperlink option... or just customize the theme so it doesn't have what you don't want. :)